# FromBody attribute doesn't work for me in RC 2

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have updated to ASP.NET RC 2 and created an empty Project for test purposes.

HomeController:

```
[Route("")]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class HomeController : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller
{
    [Route("")]
    [Route("[action]")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Route("[action]")]
    public IActionResult Login([FromBody]LoginViewModel loginVm)
    {
        return View(loginVm);
    }
}
```

Index-View:

```
<form action="Login" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="firstname"/>
    <input type="text" name="lastname"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Whenever I put the 'FromBody'-attribute to my method parameter, the 'Login' method isn't called (break point isn't reached). If I use 'FromQuery' instead of 'FromBody' everything works fine.

In RC 1 I was able to put 'FromBody' combined with 'HttpPost' attributes in method's parameters.

Where is my problem?

Comment: Can you try to add the `[HttpPost]` attribute above the `Login` method?

Comment: @Dieterg If I decorate my Method with 'HttpPost' everything works. I wonder because If I use 'HttpPost' and 'FromQuery' my method is called, but with 'HttpPost' and 'FromBody' there isn't any reach in debug....

Comment: without using `[HttpPost]` compiler ignore the `Action`..